# “urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester” in ADFS logout response

Tags: java, c#, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I get a SAML LogoutResponse with

```
 <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
```

I find reason in google :

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester- means that ADFS didn't "like" the request and blames the source of the request.
```

But I don't know why ADFS didn't "like" my request.

My web application is a  java web on spring boot (SP)

and  IDP is a .NET application.

This is my logout LogoutResponse

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                      ID="_e35423a6-fd46-460b-a3e6-7cfae545b1f3"
                      Version="2.0"
                      IssueInstant="2019-08-14T07:09:14.515Z"
                      Destination="https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443/logout"
                      Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                      InResponseTo="_c979ebc9-0379-4834-b249-13b451c9d100"
                      >
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://signin.kering.net/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

this is my logoutRequest

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                      Destination="https://signin.kering.net/adfs/ls/"
                      ID="_c979ebc9-0379-4834-b249-13b451c9d100"
                      IssueInstant="2019-08-14T07:09:14.229Z"
                      Version="2.0"
                      >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:NameID xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                  Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
                  >winston.yu-ext@kering.com</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2p:SessionIndex>_424f15d3-dc96-4d59-b2a8-a64fb2660562</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

This is my Login AuthRequest

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443/login"
                     Destination="https://signin.kering.net/adfs/ls/"
                     ID="_b45a198a-8dbb-4055-bca7-f9fc32095f45"
                     IssueInstant="2019-08-14T07:08:32.105Z"
                     ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                     Version="2.0"
                     >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
                         Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
                         />
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

This is my login Response

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                ID="_0aa50862-17e3-4c58-aa52-0bac07bda46c"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2019-08-14T07:08:37.385Z"
                Destination="https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443/login"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                InResponseTo="_b45a198a-8dbb-4055-bca7-f9fc32095f45"
                >
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://signin.kering.net/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                            >
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    </e:EncryptionMethod>
                    <KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Kering Technical CA - G2, DC=resource, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>2408480489646755950735496314893381069394937388</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <e:CipherData>
                        <e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
                    </e:CipherData>
                </e:EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

This is my login Response Decrypt xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_0aa50862-17e3-4c58-aa52-0bac07bda46c" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-08-14T07:08:37.385Z" Destination="https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443/login" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_b45a198a-8dbb-4055-bca7-f9fc32095f45">  
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://signin.kering.net/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>  
  <samlp:Status> 
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/> 
  </samlp:Status>  
  <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_424f15d3-dc96-4d59-b2a8-a64fb2660562" IssueInstant="2019-08-14T07:08:37.384Z" Version="2.0">
    <Issuer>http://signin.kering.net/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#_424f15d3-dc96-4d59-b2a8-a64fb2660562">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <ds:DigestValue>9hpL0DgKatiKPMl++uqSzT3IPmyZT0nvtlOEBTUhbfg=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>qww4n6/......DKmM=</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIJ5TCCCM2.......ac00PO876ZrlLBuE=</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <Subject>
      <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_b45a198a-8dbb-4055-bca7-f9fc32095f45" NotOnOrAfter="2019-08-14T07:13:37.385Z" Recipient="https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443/login"/>
      </SubjectConfirmation>
    </Subject>
    <Conditions NotBefore="2019-08-14T07:08:37.383Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-08-14T08:08:37.383Z">
      <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>https://guxhk1pcn01.apac.guccigroup.dom:443</Audience>
      </AudienceRestriction>
    </Conditions>
    <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn">
        <AttributeValue>winston.yu-ext@kering.com</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
        <AttributeValue>winston.yu-ext@kering.com</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
    </AttributeStatement>
    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-08-14T07:08:37.321Z">
      <AuthnContext>
        <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef>
      </AuthnContext>
    </AuthnStatement>
  </Assertion> 
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: 1. It's unclear what ADFS is doing in your architecture (_My web application is a java web on spring boot (SP) and IDP is a .NET application_) and 2. You need to grab [ADFS logs](https://support.robinpowered.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005014143-How-to-check-ADFS-logs-for-SAML-logins) for more info. Please clarify item 1 and update your post with your findings from item 2.

Comment: we use ADFS to integrated single sign-on. IDP provide a account password verification service

Answer (score 0):

Agreed - look at the event logs.

Two common reasons for logout failure.

- You are not logging out as the same user that logged in. The logout has a NameID but the login doesn't
- One side expects a signature and the other side doesn't

Comment: login request is just redirect to a login page on IDP，after input userId and password it response a  saml  whicht include userId information. finally,we directly  point to  (https://signin.kering.net/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0)  can logout successfully.But I don't know whether it is safe .